# Use association methods after overwriting accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a deck model that looks something like this:

```
class Deck < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards

  def cards
    ["ace"] + Cards.where(:deck_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

I've lost the association methods by redefining the cards accessor. For example, I can't do:

```
@deck = Deck.new
@cards = d.cards.build
```

How can I get the association methods back?

It would be nice if I could be access the original `cards` method without knowing anything about what I've done to it in advance. I think that this last caveat rules out `alias_method_chain` as a solution.

Comment: a weird requirement. how about always insert an 'ace' in the cards table for each deck?

Comment: Will there ever be a deck without cards? Why not move that cards method into a Deck initializer function rather than redefine the cards accessor?

Comment: Don't override ActiveRecord methods. It'll give you all sorts of trouble in the future. Just rename your method or association to something else. It'll make you a happy panda.

Comment: @ShiningRay and @Steph The deck model I created in the question is just for illustrative purposes. In the actual code there are two related models that contain "cards" and I usually want to return the cards from both of them. That line might be closer to the original if it was written `Chute.cards + Cards.where(:deck_id => self.id)`

Comment: @DanielWoelfel I think you should build your own association intead of override defaults. like `has_many cards, :find_sql => '...'`

Comment: In the end, it was much easier to create an all_cards method than to use method chaining, or build my own association. Thanks for all of the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed in comments, you should not override the Rails generated method as its returns not simple array - it returns `Relation` instance. For all default associations use `before_create` that will be executed before your object is created.
    class Deck < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :cards
      before_create :add_default_cards

```
  private:
  def add_default_cards
    cards.create! :name => 'ace'
  end
end
```

Comment: Adding the ace is a bit of red herring. The actual code is complicated, so I created a(n overly) simple example. The real question is "given that the ActiveRecord method has been overwritten, is there a way to use the original association methods".

Comment: Looks like `alias_method_chain` should do the trick. Or you still can define your own named method and keep rails safe. Provide more information why do you need to exactly override the rails method?